Showing the following function is nonnegative
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $g: \mathbb{R} \times D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be nonnegative functions. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $D$ such that $\mu(D) < \infty$. I would like to prove that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$h(x) = \int_D f(y)g^2(x,y) d\mu(y) - \Big(\int_D f(y)g(x,y)d\mu(y)\Big)^2 \geq 0.$$
My attempt has been to use Jensen's inequality on the second term since
$$\Big(\int_D f(y)g(x,y)d\mu(y)\Big)^2 \leq \mu(D)\int_D f^2(y)g^2(x,y)d\mu(y)$$
and so
$$h(x) \geq \int_D f(y)g^2(x,y) d\mu(y) - \mu(D)\int_D f^2(y)g^2(x,y)d\mu(y) = \int_Dg^2(x,y)f(y)\Big(1-\mu(D)f(y)\Big)d\mu(y).$$
And so $h$ is nonnegative only if $$\mu(D) \leq 1/f(y) \tag{1}$$ for all $y \in D$.
However I'm not sure if this is correct since (1) was not assumed. Is this correct or is there a more direct way to prove this?

Are you sure you're not missing any conditions on $f$? Replacing $f$ with $\lambda f$ in the desired inequality and sending $\lambda\to \infty$ seems to suggest this cannot be true.

@raj I don't have anything written down other than $f$ being $C^\infty$ so it is necessarily bounded on $D$. Would that be enough to make it true?

As far as I can see what I said would still imply this cannot hold for all such $f$. If there was a condition such as $\int_D f(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y) = 1$ then you could apply Jensen to the new measure $\mathrm{d}\nu(y) = f(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)$ to immediately get the result.

The statement is false as written, by the scaling argument above. Again, are you sure you don’t have extra assumptions on $f$? If not Jensen isn’t really helpful; perhaps you have $f\geq 0$ and $\int f ,d\mu=1$? (This constraint of course rules out the above type of scaling arguments)

@peek-a-boo Ah yes now that you mention it I forgot to include the assumption $\int f d\mu = 1$, how does that change things?

then it’s trivial: as mentioned in the above comment, you apply Jensen to the new measure $d\nu=f,d\mu$, which is a probability measure, so it’s begging to use Jensen’s inequality. Or you can use Cauchy-Schwarz (to bound the $L^1(\nu)$ norm by the $L^2(\nu)$ norm, since we’re on a finite measure space).

@raj You're right. As peek-a-boo pointed out I also have that $\int f d\mu = 1$. That is very clever, is this a standard trick? I wouldn't have thought of doing this.

@peek-a-boo Thanks, that's a really clever trick! I will remember that next time I see such an integral.

besides this ‘trick’, which is really just observation, the much more important thing to keep in mind is scaling. it is an extremely powerful theoretical tool which immediately tells you what the right/optimal exponents of an inequality ought to be (invaluable when dealing with complicated scales, especially when several Sobolev spaces are lying around). And more to the point: it tells you when an inequality obviously cannot hold (or if there’s a typo). Also, I very vividly remember pointing out this method of applying Jensen/ Cauchy-Schwarz in a previous question of yours :)

@peek-a-boo Thank you. I'm trying to get better at identifying when to use Jensen's inequality, it tends to be pretty low on the list of inequalities I first think of using when working on a problem. Could you elaborate on how one can use scaling as a theoretical tool and for establishing inequalities?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
